# find img in div and read alt text

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to find an image in an animated `<div class="text_slider">` and read the `alt=""` of it.

```
<div id="slider">
   <img src="1.png" alt="this is the first image" />
   <img src="2.png" alt="this is the second image" />
</div>
```

My attempt was:

```
function afterPic() { 
    $('.text_slider').animate({
            opacity: 0.25,
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 1000, 
        function() {
          $('.text_slider').html("<p style='z-index: 9998;'>"
                 + $('#slider').find('img').this.alt +"</p>"); 
        }
    );
```

but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Your question's HTML + JS don't match up (post the complete markup if there is more) and there are a couple syntax mistakes in your script.

Comment: $('#slider').find('img').attr('alt')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/FJfTb/

To find an item under another item you should always apply the parent selector:

```
$('#slider > img').attr('alt');
```

the > shows that #slider is the parent to the img.

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="1.png" alt="this is the first image" />
    <img src="2.png" alt="this is the second image" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
alert($('#slider > img').attr('alt'));
```

As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.  So if you are using jQuery newer than 1.6 please replace attr with prop

Comment: ive a question about this, just for the clearence. Why is it better to use `'#slider > img'` as selector compared with `find`method?

Comment: you can use the find method still, but your selector should still be '#slider > img' if your img is under an item with the id of "slider" this is because you are narrowing the scope that jquery searches.  Instead of searching the whole page, it will just search under the item id of "slider", hence speeding up the search.  However, if you are using $('#slider').find('img').prop('alt') then these are basically applying the same function, except that you are DOM locating two objects.  I'd have to write a test to see if speed would be nominal but I bet it would be.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation! but theres one thing im struggling with, im using `cycle.js` and i only get displayed the `alt` of the first image (in this case `1.png`). How can i actually read the `alt` of the current img.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the quotes around `'#slider'` and are using jQuery wrong...

It will do the trick: `$('#slider').find('img').attr('alt')`

Comment: oh that was a oversight because i typed it new! thanks, yours works pretty good! :)

Answer (score 2):

OK, two things.

You reference the class `.text_slider` that doesn't exist in your markup and your div has an id of `#slider`. To get the `alt` in jQuery, you should use the `prop()` function. `alt` is a property of a  JavaScript DOM object, not a jQuery object.

```
function afterPic() { 
    $('.text_slider').animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        height: 'toggle'
    }, 1000, function() {
           $('.text_slider').html("<p style='z-index: 99998;'>" + 
           $('#slider').find('img').prop('alt') + ":</p>"); 
    });
}
```